# Como retornar os itens selecionados em um <select multiple> com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso receber os valores de um $('select[multiple]').val() separados por vírgula. Por exemplo.

O código HTML:

```
<select id="estado" multiple>
<option selected>SP</option>
<option selected>RJ</option>
<option selected>ES</option>
<option>MG</option>
</select>
```

O código JavaScript com jQuery:

```
const estados = $('#estado').val(); //Resultado: SPRJES
```

Como fazer para o retorno de estados ser "SP, RJ, ES" caso esses fossem selecionados?

Está retornando tudo junto.

Obrigado

Comment: Como o retorno está agora?

Comment: Explica melhor o que tu quer fazer, mostra mais código. Dá um exemplo de uma entrada e qual seria o resultado desejado.

Comment: Erlon, apliquei ao um select de escolha multipla, ele retorna tudo junto, SP,RJ,ES,MG, preciso de um espaço entre eles, ex.: SP, RJ, ES

Comment: Negativaram minha pergunta porque? Se é tão banal porque não me ajudaram?

Comment: Fala, amigo. Melhorei a escrita da sua pergunta. Acabou irritando alguns rsrsrs. Coloquei a resposta que precisa. Veja lá.

Comment: Obrigado novamente Sergio, tentei ser breve, não achei que a pergunta estava mal feita, mas com sua edição ficou melhor! Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é usar a função de array `join`.

Veja como fica nesse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/7tfcyjuv/

HTML:

```
<select id="estado" multiple>
<option>SP</option>
<option>RJ</option>
<option>ES</option>
<option>MG</option>
</select>
```

**Código JavaScript com sua solicitação:**

```
const estados = $('#estado').val().join(', '); //Resultado: SP, RJ, ES
```

Comment: Perfeito Sergio! Obrigado!